# Melting Pandas Dataframe and separate the value column based on its data type

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a Dataframe being read from CSV which looks roughly like this

```
date         1      2       3       4
05-10-2019   20     32      43.5    Auto
06-10-2019   19     Off     54.6    Auto
07-10-2019   Off    45      37      Auto
```

Each parameter (1, 2, 3, etc) can have either a float value or a string value. Is there any way I can melt the data so that the value column will be separated on the parameter's datatype? When the value is a string the parameter would have the value `None` for its float column and if the value is a float its string column value would be `None`.

In the end the dataframe would look like this

```
date        parameter   value   message
05-10-2019  1           20      None
05-10-2019  2           32      None
05-10-2019  3           43.5    None
05-10-2019  4           None    Auto
06-10-2019  1           19      None
06-10-2019  2           None    Off
06-10-2019  3           54.6    None
................
07-10-2019  4           None    Auto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), then convert values to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` create missing values for non numeric, so is possible use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for non numeric column with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df = df.melt('date', var_name='parameter')
s = pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce')
df = df.assign(value = s, message = df['value'].where(s.isna()))
print (df)
          date parameter  value message
0   05-10-2019         1   20.0     NaN
1   06-10-2019         1   19.0     NaN
2   07-10-2019         1    NaN     Off
3   05-10-2019         2   32.0     NaN
4   06-10-2019         2    NaN     Off
5   07-10-2019         2   45.0     NaN
6   05-10-2019         3   43.5     NaN
7   06-10-2019         3   54.6     NaN
8   07-10-2019         3   37.0     NaN
9   05-10-2019         4    NaN    Auto
10  06-10-2019         4    NaN    Auto
11  07-10-2019         4    NaN    Auto
```

If order is important:

```
df = df.melt('date', var_name='parameter').sort_values(['date','parameter'])
s = pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce')
df = df.assign(value = s, message = df['value'].where(s.isna()))
print (df)
         date parameter  value message
0  2019-05-10         1   20.0     NaN
3  2019-05-10         2   32.0     NaN
6  2019-05-10         3   43.5     NaN
9  2019-05-10         4    NaN    Auto
1  2019-06-10         1   19.0     NaN
4  2019-06-10         2    NaN     Off
7  2019-06-10         3   54.6     NaN
10 2019-06-10         4    NaN    Auto
2  2019-07-10         1    NaN     Off
5  2019-07-10         2   45.0     NaN
8  2019-07-10         3   37.0     NaN
11 2019-07-10         4    NaN    Auto
```